# JavaScript: Keep scrolling down page

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript. I want to scroll to the very bottom of a website that continually loads more text when you scroll down (like on a Facebook page).

I know the code `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)` will scroll to the bottom, causing more of the page to load, but not yet all of it. I was wondering how to execute this until the actual bottom of the page has loaded, or ~100 times.

I tried a `for` loop, but it didn't scroll more than once. Then I tried a `for` loop with `setTimeout` set to 2000 ms (or 2 sec) which also did not work for some reason.

I'm also worried that the page will try to run my code all at once before loading more of the content.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are using Ajax to load your contents. Can we see the Ajax code?

Comment: `I want to scroll to the very bottom of a website that continually loads more text when you scroll down (like on a Facebook page)`. How you are continuously loading data. I think you are `Ajax` for that. Can we see that code?

Comment: @MahbubulIslam - The webpage is not constructed by me, so I don't have the code. I just want to navigate it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, inspired by some other code I found online. I did:

```
function scrolldown() {
  setTimeout(
    function()
    {
      window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
      scrolldown();
    }, 2000
  )
}

scrolldown()
```

Still unsure why the delayed for loop did not work though.
The unsuccessful for loop attempt was:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  setTimeout(
    function(){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);}, 2000
  )
}
```

Comment: Your loop tells it to wait 2 seconds 100 times. This means that in 2 seconds the document gets told to scroll to the same place 100 times!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same using scrollBy function :

```
function scrolldown() {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      window.scrollBy(0,50);
      scrolldown();
    }, 1000)
}
scrolldown()
```

while `window.scrollBy(x,y)` used to scroll x & y from Top Left of the page.